# How do I reference a variable from a CSV Feeder in Gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm trying to feed URLs into a Gatling simulation from a CSV file and I'm getting the following error:

> 11:48:01.967 [ERROR] i.g.h.a.HttpRequestAction - 'httpRequest-1' failed to execute: No attribute named 'Url' is defined

My data file looks like this:

```
Url
/foo
/bar
```

And my simulation is as follows:

```
val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL("https://example.com")

val csvFeeder = csv("urls.csv").random

val scn = scenario("Simulation")
          .feed(csvFeeder)
          .exec(http("request_0")
            .get("${Url}")
          )

setUp(scn.inject(
    atOnceUsers(1),
    rampUsers(3) over(5 seconds),
    constantUsersPerSec(3) during(600 seconds) randomized
)).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

If I debug the simulation (I'm using IntelliJ FYI) I can see `csvFeeder` has 2 records, each record is a `Tuple2` and if I dig in to that I can see that `_1 = "Url"` and `_2 = "/foo"` so the feeder is loading the data.

Why am I getting the error *No attribute named 'Url' is defined* ?

I'm using Gatling version 2.1.7.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out the issue was due to the input CSV file having a UTF-8 BOM. Removing the BOM fixed the issue.

Comment: Good catch! No, I wasn't aware of this issue. In Gatling 2.2, we're switching CSV parser (from opencsv to jackson-dataformat-csv) so I wonder if the issue would get fixed.

Comment: Answering to myself: thanks to jackson-dataformat-csv, Gatling 2.2 will properly handle BOM. see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv/issues/47

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it the right way.

Possible explanations:

- You're not loading the same file when running Gatling and when debugging from IntelliJ
- You actually have a typo in your column header

Comment: I get the same output when I Run or Debug from IntelliJ. 
I've triple checked the headers; I've changed it to `x` and appended comma to all lines (to make sure there was no white space in the header), it still looks good in the debugger (the first item of the tuple is `"x"`) and switched my `get()` to `"${x}"` but still no dice: " failed to execute: No attribute named 'x' is defined"

Comment: Which Gatling version do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.7.

Comment: it appears to have been an issue with the UTF-8 BOM in the input file. I've removed the BOM and the file loads fine. Are you aware of any difficulty reading files with a BOM?